# Fill Table from multiple data sets in Microsoft report viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dataset, microsoft-reporting, report-viewer2012, reportviewerformvc

I have data base with 2 tables "Orders" & "Materials" . In Report data I have created data set named "Orders" which carry columns "Material ID" , "Description" , "Quantity" . I have added table to my report and linked it with orders data set . I want to replace Material ID by it's value from Material Table , I want to write some thing like query to run dynamically in the table . Please advice. thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an MSSQL query?

Comment: yes i want to fill table with query @EricS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an [Inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

```
SELECT o.Description, o.Quantity, m.Material
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Materials m
ON o.MaterialID = m.MaterialID
```

Comment: OK ,Its great . Now I need to run this query to my table in the MS Report Viewer .

Comment: @prime I'm not totally sure if its the same Report Viewer tool but this might be helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252073.aspx